# multiple versions of stdlib.h

Tags: c++, linux

I was trying to compile a program and stdlib.h didn't seem to exsist. When I tried to search for it I seem to be able to find 4 versions of stdlib.h. I was wondering how one can correct this issue:

```
:6:20: fatal error: stdlid.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdlid.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.

sudo find / -name 'stdlib.h'
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdlib.h
/usr/include/stdlib.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib.h
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/stdlib.h
```

Comment: Lower-case D is not the same as lower-case B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stdli**d**.h is wrong, you need a b instead of a d